# variables as decorator arguments

Tags: python, decorator

I have found out that decorator arguments are passed at decorator definition rather than invocation like with functions.

Now I wonder if it is possible to make the decorater get the value of a variable at runtime like this, the decorater should print the current value of state instead of the one it head at definition:

```
def deco(msg):
    def decorater(func):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            print msg
            func(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper
    return decorater


def func():
    local = {
        "state": None
    }

    @deco(local["state"])
    def test():
        pass

    def setState(newState):
        local["state"] = newState

    setState("start")
    test()
    setState("test")
    test()

func()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

John you should read [this](http://robertheaton.com/2014/02/09/pythons-pass-by-object-reference-as-explained-by-philip-k-dick/). In python, the variable is not the object. You question, is it "possible to make the decorator get the value of a variable at runtime", doesn't make sense because of python's scoping rules. The decorator function does not generally have access to the scope where `state` is defined. There are several ways you could get the behavior you want though.

Without knowing the specifics of what you're trying to do, here are two that might work. The first uses closure:

```
state = None
def with_closure(f):
     def helper(*args, **kwargs):
        # state is in scope for this function
        print "Current state is: {}.".format(state)
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
     return helper

@with_closure
def foo():
    return "something"
```

Or you could make an object to keep track of state:

```
class StateHolder:
    def set_state(self, state):
        self.state = state

def with_state_object(state_object):
    def decorator(f):
        def helper(*args, **kwargs):
            print "Current state is: {}.".format(state_object.state)
            return f(*args, **kwargs)
        return helper
    return decorator

global_state = StateHolder()
global_state.set_state("some state")

@with_state_object(global_state)
def foo():
    return "something"
```

Answer (score 2):

In your example, `deco()` is a decorator *factory*; you're creating the decorator which will then immediately be invoked. More generally, you *invoke* a decorator at the time that you're *defining* the function that you're decorating.

You can do what you're trying to do with minimal changes by just not passing in `state`, and accessing it as a global from within `wrapper()`, in which case you don't need `deco()`; you could just use `@decorator` directly. That said, I think there are better ways to do what you're trying to do.

Comment: what am I trying to do is pass arguments to a decorator. I want this argument to have the data which it has at the time the function is INVOKED not at DEFINITION.

Comment: @JohnSmith, edit your question with your actual code which is trying to actually do what you want, and I'll be able to answer better.

Comment: I can't post 20k lines of code here. The example I have provided does demonstrate the issue. I don't know why you have such problems understanding the difference between invocation and definition... if you call the test function the decorator will print the argument it had at definition. I want it to print the argument value it has at invocation.

Comment: Why do you think I have 'such problems' understanding the difference? I use both words to explain different things in my answer. I also did tell you how to do what you're trying to do, I just said that there are better ways to do it, and asked for more context so I could better help you.

Comment: because you ask me what I want to happen while I have allready explained it twice. Then why don't you enlighten me about the better ways

Comment: @JohnSmith, there are many different ways, depending on exactly what you're trying to do. Without specifics, it's hard to say.